# How to make UWP apps compatible with windows 8.1

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp, xamarin.winphone

I have installed Visual studio 2017 and Visual studio 2015.

Using visual studio 2015 I am able to create Xamarin.winphone projects and I am able to run this app on windows 8,8.1,10

Using visual studio 2017 I am able to create Xamarin.uwp projects and while Creating it I would like to support windows 8 as well .. but in minimum version I am not able to find it

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp) is Windows 10 only, so the lowest target is the first Windows 10 Build 10240

> The **Universal Windows Platform (UWP) is the app platform for Windows
>   10**. You can develop apps for UWP with just one API set, one app package, and one store to reach all Windows 10 devices – PC, tablet,
>   phone, Xbox, HoloLens, Surface Hub and more.

Answer (score 1):

> Using visual studio 2017 I am able to create Xamarin.uwp projects and while Creating it I would like to support windows 8 as well .. but in minimum version I am not able to find it

The solution with windows 8 client project has no longer been supported by Xamarin template. But you could add windows 8 client project manually. Please   follow [Adding a Windows Phone App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/phone/).

It is xamarin native PCL project in your screenshot. The PCL project is a protable library referenced by each native platforms. You could also add a new windowsphone native project that reference PCL project. Please refer to the following steps.

1. Create a cross platform app.

[image]

2. Add a new WindowsPhone native project that reference PCL project.

[image]

Please notice that you could not use Xamrin.Forms control in your native project. For example you could not use Entry in "myproject.IOS" , it is suitable to use UITextField.

```
public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
     UITextField textInPut = new UITextField();
     textInPut.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 120, 44);
     textInPut.Text = "Xamarin IOS Native ";
     View.AddSubview(textInPut);
}
```

The [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/XamarinNativeTest.git) has uploaded to github. Please check.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit ? It seem like this solutions is for windows.forms project but I am using Xamarin Native like myproject.ios,myproject.droid and myproject.winphone

Comment: It is xamarin native  PCL project in your screenshot. The PCL project is a protable library referenced by each native platforms. You could also add a new windowsphone native project that reference PCL project.

Comment: Please notice that you could not use Xamrin.Forms control in your native project. For example you could not use `Entry` in "myproject.IOS" , it is suitable to use `UITextField`.

Comment: If you don't mind Can you explain me how to do it in Xamarin native

Comment: How did you add windows phone project.. Can you explain it please

Comment: @RajanM You could refer to [Adding a Windows Phone App](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/phone/).

Comment: This is for Xamarin.forms I am looking to add for Xamarin native.